# create certificateRequest from base64 string in .net Framework 4.7.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, x509certificate

In the past I used for our `certTool` the com `CERTENROLLLib` to create the `csr`. Since Version `4.7.2` you can use the .net Framework.

It is possible to create the `csr` by passing all the necessary Attributes in the `CreateSigningRequest` Method and convert it into a `pem` `base64` string.

Unfortunately I couldn't find the other way around, copy a csr in pem Format in a field and read all the `csr` Attributes from it (cn, san, organization, etc.)

I don't want to use the com lib `CERTENROLLLib`, openssl or other 3rd parties.

Here is what I have done (to get the csr pem string) found good examples in here and at MS Framework class description, thanks for your help

```
protected void createButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string csr_cn = txtb_csr_cn.Text;
        string csr_c = txtb_csr_c.Text;
        string csr_l = txtb_csr_l.Text;
        string csr_o = txtb_csr_o.Text;
        string csr_ou = txtb_csr_ou.Text;
        string csr_s = txtb_csr_s.Text;
        csr_san = sanMemo.Text.Replace(" ", "");
        if (csr_san.IndexOf(csr_cn) == -1)
        {
            if (csr_san == "")
            {
                csr_san = csr_cn;
            }
            else
            {
                csr_san = csr_cn + "," + csr_san;
            }
        }
        csr_key_size = Convert.ToInt32(combobox_csr_key.Text);
        csr_info = "CN=" + csr_cn + "," + "OU=" + csr_ou + "," + "O=" + csr_o + "," + "L=" + csr_l + "," + "S=" + csr_s + "," + "C=" + csr_c;
        notesMemo.Text = CreateCSR(); //CreateRequest();

    }

public static string CreateCSR()
    {
        string[] arrSeperator = new string[] { "," };

        RSA keySize = RSA.Create(csr_key_size);

        CertificateRequest parentReq = new CertificateRequest(csr_info,
            //"CN=Experimental Issuing Authority",
            keySize,
            HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
            RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

        parentReq.CertificateExtensions.Add(
            new X509BasicConstraintsExtension(true, false, 0, true));

        parentReq.CertificateExtensions.Add(
            new X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension(parentReq.PublicKey, false));


        var sanBuilder = new SubjectAlternativeNameBuilder();
        Array arrsan = csr_san.Split(arrSeperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string sanvalue in arrsan)
        {
            sanBuilder.AddDnsName(sanvalue);
        }

        parentReq.CertificateExtensions.Add(sanBuilder.Build());

        string csrdecrypt = PemEncodeSigningRequest(parentReq);
        return csrdecrypt;
```

}

```
public static string PemEncodeSigningRequest(CertificateRequest request)
    {
        byte[] pkcs10 = request.CreateSigningRequest();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.AppendLine("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----");

        string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(pkcs10);

        int offset = 0;
        const int LineLength = 64;

        while (offset < base64.Length)
        {
            int lineEnd = Math.Min(offset + LineLength, base64.Length);
            builder.AppendLine(base64.Substring(offset, lineEnd - offset));
            offset = lineEnd;
        }

        builder.AppendLine("-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----");
        string tester2 = builder.ToString();
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no pure-managed way to read a Certification Signing Request without third party libraries.

You could try using a P/Invoke to [CryptDecodeObjectEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptdecodeobjectex), possibly using the structure identifier of `X509_CERT` (per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecCrypto/constants-for-cryptencodeobject-and-cryptdecodeobject).

But the CertificateRequest class is a PKCS#10 writer without a reader in .NET Framework.

**Update (2023-01-30)**: [LoadSigningRequestPem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.certificaterequest.loadsigningrequestpem?view=net-7.0) and friends were added in .NET 7.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it seems that you do a lot in the area certificates and .net.
I your opinion, what would be the best library to work with?

Comment: thank you for your answer, it seems that you do a lot in the area certificates and .net.
In your opinion, what would be the best library to work with?
- CERTENROLLLib
- Nuget openssl.net
- other

Comment: Thank you all,, I use now bouncy castle